# Is it safe to delete historic MyBusiness Organisational Unit?

Tags: active-directory

I have multiple Windows Server 2012 Domain Controllers. I have tidied up our domain computers and users but we have a MyBusiness Organisational Unit from when the company ran a single Small Business Server.

I have moved any remaining computers and users from `MyBusiness\Computers\SBSComputers` and `MyBusiness\Users\SBSUsers` in to the main `Computers` and `Users` containers.

The only thing remaining in the MyBusiness Organisational Unit are the empty Security Groups in `MyBusiness\Security Groups`. I assume that these are Small Business Server specific and since we are no longer running in a Small Business Server environment, these can be deleted?

And in `MyBusiness\Users\SBSUsers` I have `Cloneable Domain Controllers`, `HelpLibraryUpdaters` and `Protected Users` Security Groups somehow. Are these also Small Business Server specific and can be deleted?